# AHK V2 Class extends troubles

Tags: class, autohotkey, extends, ahk2

I'm not sure if I'm using classes wrong, but any assistance would be appreciated. I'm using Autohotkey V2 and I'm trying to make a class extend to another class.

```
Class Person{
  __New(info){
    this.name := info.name
    this.age := info.age
  }
}

Class Teacher extends Person{
  __New(subject){
    this.subject := subject
  }
}

Class Student extends Person{
  __New(deskLocation){
    this.deskLocation := deskLocation
  }
}
```

I figure laying out the classes like this works because every Teacher and Student is a Person but Teachers and Students are different. So, when I declare my Teacher or Student class I use

```
T1 := Teacher("gym")
S1 := Student(11)
```

Which works fine, however, I'm not sure how I should be setting the properties for each Person.

I've tried researching, lol, but haven't found a solution. Which makes me think I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. I've also thought about declaring the properties in the Person Class and then assigning them in the Teacher and Student Classes through a method

```
Class Person{
    name := ""
    age := ""
}

Class Teacher extends Person{
  __New(subject, name, age){
    this.subject := subject
    this.Define("Name","Age")
  }

  Define(name, age) {
    this.name := name
    this.age := age
  }
}
```

but this would be highly repetitive because I would need to do it for each property then may as well just remove the Person class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2

class Person
{
    __New(info)
    {
        this.name := info.name
        this.age  := info.age
    }
}

class Teacher extends Person
{
    __New(info, subject)
    {
        super.__New(info)
        this.subject := subject
    }
}

class Student extends Person
{
    __New(info, deskLocation)
    {
        super.__New(info)
        this.deskLocation := deskLocation
    }
}

t1 := Teacher({name: "Nikola",age: 100}, "Spanish")
MsgBox(t1.name " " t1.age)
MsgBox(t1 is Person)
MsgBox(t1 is Teacher)
```